# Symfony2 embedded entity form type

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

In my Symfony2 (2.0 at present) application, I have a table of sites, each of which is assigned to a "site group". I have an event listener which sets the current site and site group as properties of a site manager class in an onKernelRequest function.

On the backend CMS, I want to give admins the ability to select which sites their content appears on (ManyToMany relationship), but only allow them to select from the sites which belong to the current site group. Consider the following:

```
Site group 1:           Site group 2:
    site1.com               site3.com
    site2.com               site4.com
```

If an admin on site1.com tries to add content, they will see only site1.com and site2.com as options, whereas an admin on site4.com will only see site3.com and site4.com.

These options will be embedded in various forms across the CMS, and in order to display only the correct sites, I can do the following from within the e.g. NewsPostType:

```
$siteGroup = $siteManager->getSiteGroup();

$builder->add('sites', 'entity', array(
    'class'         => 'MyBundle:Site',
    'multiple'      => true,
    'expanded'      => true,
    'property'      => 'name',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($siteGroup) {
        $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('s');
        return $qb->andWhere('s.siteGroup = :siteGroup')
            ->setParameter('siteGroup', $siteGroup);
    },
));
```

This correctly displays only those sites which belong to the current site group.

However, in order to do this, I have to define each FormType that I want to include these options in as a service in order to inject the "siteManager" object, so to avoid this, I thought about creating a new FormType which could have the manager injected into it and be included as follows:

```
$builder->add('sites', 'siteGroupSites');
```

The siteGroupSites type is defined as follows:

```
<?php

class SiteGroupSitesType extends AbstractType
{
    private $siteManager;

    public function __construct($siteManager) {
        $this->siteManager = $siteManager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
        $currentSite = $this->siteManager->getCurrentSite();
        $siteGroup   = $currentSite ? $currentSite->getSiteGroup() : null;

        $builder->add('sites', 'entity', array(
            'class'         => 'MyBundle:Site',
            'multiple'      => true,
            'expanded'      => true,
            'property'      => 'name',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($siteGroup) {
                $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('s');
                return $qb->andWhere('s.siteGroup = :siteGroup')
                    ->setParameter('siteGroup', $siteGroup);
            },
        ));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Me\MyBundle\Entity\Site',
        );
    }
}
```

If I try to include the site options as above, I get the following:

```
Expected argument of type "Me\MyBundle\Entity\Site", 
"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given
```

I think I might need a DataTransformer of some description, but am unsure how to tackle this. I would also like to display the options list in twig by just using

```
{{ form_row(form.sites) }}
```

Instead of what I think would be required (since form.sites is the embedded form, and form.sites.sites would be the sites property of the embedded form):

```
{{ form_row(form.sites.sites) }}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to accomplish these?

Comment: Could you post somewhere your whole FormType (siteGroupSites) ?

Comment: @Lashus I have updated the question to include the siteGroupSites code

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try settings data_class to null below.

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'Me\MyBundle\Entity\Site',
    );
}
```

Comment: when I try that I get 'Neither property "sites" nor method "getSites()" nor method "isSites()" exists in class "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection"'

Comment: In view use {{ form_row(form.sites) }} :)

Comment: I am using `{{ form_row(form.sites) }}` but I get the error message above. I think it's due to the fact that `$builder->add('sites', 'siteGroupSites');` in the parent Type is then binding the child type incorrectly, so the first element in the parent collection bound is the child collection, instead of the first element in the child collection.

Comment: It is possible. Although maybe you should use Collection of Forms? (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)